# Android - Creating own buttons in webview, retrieving certain contents from website into webview

Tags: android, webview

I'm currently doing a application (project) on android. I would like to know how to create my own buttons in webview, or creating a tab bar in webview. Also, I would want to retrieve certain contents from a website (or rather, from livejournal, to be specifc), like, I do not want the buttons that are in livejournal itself, I just want certain contents, maybe like some live journal posts. Is there any way I could do this?

Thank you so much in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of putting tabs in the WebView you should put the WebView in Tabs.  As for pulling information from LiveJournal there are two possibilites.  They either have a public api that you can access to get the data you want and use that to populate your app or they don't.  If they don't your only recourse would be to pull in the raw html and try to parse it.  At that point you might was well just use the webpage as is.

Comment: Because the livejournal is somehow a blogshop, so I was thinking of making it into an Android application. May I know how do I pull in the raw html and try to parse it? Does this mean that I only take in only the contents and display the page in my own layout in Android? By the way, the livejournal is using css, is there any problem?? Thank you so much for answering, really!! :D